# How to avoid single digit matches when using strptime of Time::PIece

Tags: perl

I am using `%y-%m-%d-%h`.  to match the values. But it generates single values. And I want two digit values like `01` for months.  I am using `strptime` function of `Time::piece` in perl.

Comment: What are you talking about? Time::Piece doesn't "generate single values". It return a Time::Piece object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5645626/nishant-midha can you please guide me on this also

Answer (score 1):

Forgive and fix:

```
my $tp = eval { Time::Piece->strptime($date , '%y-%m-%d-%h') };
if ($@) {
   die("Wrong format");
}

$date = $tp->strftime('%y-%m-%d-%h');
```

Strictly enforce:

```
if ($date !~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\z/) {
   die("Wrong format");
}

if (!eval { Time::Piece->strptime($date , '%y-%m-%d-%h') }) {
   die("Wrong format");
}
```

Comment: Actually.  I am. Taking input from user. In yyyy-mm-dd-hh.  Format. And. I want to. Put validation. Of values. Like.   If.  User. Entering value.  Of month. More then 12. Then.  It should. Disply message that.  Wrong format has been entered. .so.  I am.  Using. eval { Time::piece->strptime($date , '%y-%m-%d-%h") };  and.   If($@){ print. "Wrong format";    but what is happening it is. Checking that. Month is between 1 to 12. And date is between 1 to. 31.  But.   It is also parsing when. I enter. Month value. As.  1.   But I want month in. Two digit format like 01.

Comment: You appear to be trying to clarify your question. In the future, do so by editing your question. Feel free to let me know when you do by posting a comment here.

Comment: Now that is some crazy punctuation.

Comment: TLP. Sent. On move and its auto dictionary's outcome so pls. Excuse typo